# Who is up-voting who on SO.com?

Tags: discussion, reputation, up-votes

I'm interested on the correlation between the reputation of SO members and the number of votes.

Is there a chart giving this correlation: for example the mean of up-votes given by week and by reputation range and also the mean of up-votes received by week and by reputation range? Globally and also separated for questions and answers.

I suspect that a big part of the up-votes are given people with a low reputation to people with a high reputation, but without any figures I can not comment.

So, Who is up-voting who on SO.com?

Comment: i'm upvoting you on SO.  but only on alternate tuesdays when i forget my password.  (seriously, tho, voting histories are anonymized; that data isn't generally accessible.)

Comment: I'm not asking the raw data, just the statistics.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you'd have to parse out of the data dump.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/